Using Python to create an RSS feed - but would like to display the feed locally
I've created a project that creates an RSS feed. This RSS feed will be sent to a company that will wrap it and create their own prettier RSS feed with it, but is there a tool or extension that devs use to display their RSS feed locally? I know that xml is very similar to html - and I can parse things by just searching and finding what I need, but I'd really like to see it displayed. Might be a dumb question, but I figured that I'd ask because there have to be devs out there creating and also displaying their own RSS feeds locally. Very new to RSS feeds and the team that's been doing this doesn't have anything. Thanks!
I have tried chrome extensions inoreader and rss feed reader, but they don't work with local - behind my company's authentication wall (really this is the clear problem) - and I'd really like to render this locally so that I can see what it looks like.

This question is similar to: Pretty printing XML in Python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
